# Change elements of boolean matrix to True based on value from another array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to update the values of False elements in my boolean matrix to True based on the index value of that row which is contained in another numpy array.

Here is my array, `change`, that identifies the element that needs to be changed in the matrix, `mask_matrix`:

```
import numpy as np
mask_matrix = np.zeros((20, 25), dtype=bool)

change = np.array([ 6., 22., 22., 22., 22., 21., 22., 21., 17., 21., 22., 21., 22.,
       21., 22., 12.,  7.,  7., 12., 17.])
```

So every item in `change` tells which element to change in `mask_matrix`. E.g. `change[0] = 6.` should change the first row and 6th column to a 6 in the `mask_matrix`

I know I can change items like this,

```
mask[0,:][6] = True
```

But I need to find a more efficient way of doing this.

Does anybody have any advice as to how to do this? Preferably vectorised.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should help:

```
mask_matrix[np.arange(change.size),change]=True
```

Which is basically using advanced indexing in numpy to call row-column elements of an array.